# Which parts of bootstrap are required?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm now using [bootstrap-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-loader) package. With it you can configure which parts of Bootstrap to use with [`styles` and `scripts`](https://github.com/shakacode/bootstrap-loader/blob/v2.0.0-beta.3/.bootstraprc-3-default#L50-L116) configuration options. Most likely it mimics what you can select on [Customize Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) page. Most of it is self-explanatory. But not all.

Considering styles. You most likely need `mixins`. They might be used by any other part of Bootstrap code. `normalize` also looks like thing not to disable. Then, `scaffolding`... What exactly is that? `component-animations`? Probably, it's best not to disable. `close`? I can disable just `close` buttons? Probably, better leave it enabled. `utilities`? `responsive-utilities`?

Considering scripts. `transitions`? `collapse`? Which parts of Bootstrap use them?

In other words, which parts you most likely don't want to disable? Especially the ones you might not notice right away. Are there any nonobvious relationships between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS:

Yes, you shouldn't remove `mixins`, `normalize` and `scaffolding` (basic styles for `html`, `body` elements and things like that).
`close` is related to alerts (dismissable) and modals.
`utilities` and `responsive-utilities` - you can remove them if you don't use it (classes like `hidden`, `visible-sm`, `text-left` etc.). And if you for example use `navbars` you should include `nav` component. And probably `input-groups` won't work without `forms` components. Similar with `buttons` and `button-groups`.

Scripts:

[Transition.js](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#transitions) is used by other Bootstrap plugins (like `collapse` to check if browser supports CSS transitions and collapse plugin is related to CSS `component-animations`).

[Button.js](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons) - this feature is deprecated since v3.3.5 and has been removed in v4.

Popovers require the tooltip plugin to be included in your version of Bootstrap.

I think the rest is self-explanatory.

Comment: I may be overly cautious here, but I came to the following basic setup. Styles: `mixins`, `normalize`, `scaffolding`, `type`, `component-animations`, `utilities`, `responsive-utilities`. Scripts: `transition`, `collapse`. You may need `print` for print media. Probably `forms` for things like buttons or something. With the rest it must be more or less clear, whether you need it enabled or not.

Comment: It really depend on your needs (what you want to write by yourself and what you want to use without coding). With your basic setup you won't have grid system, I'm assuming you are fine with this. And if you want to use collapse you MAY need panels component for styled accordions and toggles (but your collapse.js will work just fine without panels but you will have to style it by yourself). Your setup is fine, it's very basic. Maybe try to build something from scratch without Bootstrap using only normalize, you can easily build collapse if you know basic JS/jQuery.

Comment: My main concern was to not miss something needed by other parts of Bootstrap. Like, safe defaults. With the rest of the "parts", things seem to be more or less clear. Like, if I use grid, I need to enable `grid`. If I use alerts, I need to enable `alerts`. There are probably some not always obvious dependencies between parts. Some of them you mentioned. You've got my thanks for that. Some of them I'm about to discover myself. Maybe. But the groundwork has been laid :) If I may say so...